# DocuSign not accepting Salesforce user in sandbox

Tags: docusignapi

I have installed DocuSign on my customers full sandbox and the installation was successful.  I then went out and created and then activated my demo account for DocuSign.  I logged back in to Salesforce and went to the DocuSign Admin tab and attempted to finalize the DocuSign connect to Salesforce.  This is where my problem is...

The Salesforce user is throwing the following error when I first login to the admin area:
Invalid DocuSign Connect Configuration for the Account

If I attempt to update the Salesforce user I get:
Invalid Salesforce Credentials

I have checked the access being used and the information entered is correct.  I have selected "Sandbox" as the Salesforce environment and since we use IP ranges there is no security token requirement.

Has anyone resolved this issue?  Since we have not finalized our contract with DocuSign I have received absolutely no support from DocuSign on resolving this issue with their application.

Thank you, 
Chris Frei

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is login to your demo DocuSign account through demo.docusign.net, then configure your Connect settings through the Preferences area.  After logging in click your profile icon in the top right of the screen, then go to

```
Preferences -> Connect
```

Make sure you have your Connect settings configured correctly on that screen.  If you do not have a Connect config setup yet then create one.